# Foreman Puppet Class Order

Tags: foreman

I am new to Foreman and there are some problems getting startet!
How the application of puppet classes can be ordered in Foreman? 
Is there a possibility not using puppet stages?

Thanks a lot!
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean without an proper example of your problem.

However if you are referring to how you can make one puppet class run before another one you can use the so called [Relationship Metaparameters](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html)

before — Applies a resource before the target resource.
require — Applies a resource after the target resource.

```
package { 'openssh-server':
  ensure => present,
  before => Class['someclass'],
}
```

Otherwise you can use something called require (not to be confused with the require metaparameter above)

The require function declares one or more classes, then causes them to become a dependency of the surrounding container.

```
define apache::vhost (Integer $port, String $docroot, String $servername, String $vhost_name) {
  require apache
  ...
}
```

In the above example, Puppet will ensure that every resource in the apache class gets applied before every resource in any apache::vhost instance.

more information [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#class-parameters-and-variables)